# Easy PHP Unexpected end of Apache

Tags: php, apache, easyphp

My EasyPHP server suddenly stops working, it has happened before, and I changed the port to 8080, but now it does not work again.

I checked whether there are any processes using my port using `netstat` but there aren't any apps using the port.

Here are what is written in the log:

```
18/08 15:43:25 EasyPHP Apache CreateProcess "C:\PROGRA~2\EasyPHP\binaries\apache\bin\eds-httpd.exe"
18/08 15:43:26 EasyPHP ServerBase::TimerProc : GetProcessVersion Apache (pid: 7656) error 5
18/08 15:43:26 EasyPHP Apache  Unexpected end of Apache !
```

And when I go to eds-httpd.exe to try and run it, it would say "**no listening sockets available, please try again**

I have no clue what's going on, please advise.

Comment: Anything in the apache error log?

Comment: Have you running anything else on Port 80? Skype for example?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I don't have any other apps running. And apparently the error is my IP

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update**

I found my error. Apparently my IP has changed from 10.0.1.15 to 10.0.1.14

I found it from ipconfig and changed the config in httpd.conf